# DB2: Display the 7 days starting from last saturday, including days in the future

Tags: sql, db2, dayofweek

What i have so far:

This query:

```
SELECT to_char(creationdate, 'DD-MM-YY') AS DATE
    ,sum(CASE 
            WHEN internalpriority >= 3
                THEN 1
            ELSE 0
            END) AS

CLOSE
FROM incident
WHERE creationdate BETWEEN (
                SELECT DISTINCT (CURRENT_timestamp - (DAYOFWEEK(CURRENT_timestamp) - 0) DAYS - (hour(current_timestamp)) hours - (minute(current_timestamp)) minute) AS MONDAY_OF_CURRENT_WEEK_DATE
                FROM incident
                )
        AND (
                SELECT DISTINCT (CURRENT_timestamp - (DAYOFWEEK(CURRENT_timestamp) - 6) DAYS - (hour(current_timestamp)) hours - (minute(current_timestamp)) minute) AS MONDAY_OF_CURRENT_WEEK_DATE
                FROM incident
                )
GROUP BY to_char(creationdate, 'DD-MM-YY')
```

gets me this result (today is the 17th, so the 14th was last saturday, all good so far)

```
14-02-15    307
15-02-15    296
16-02-15    687
17-02-15    357
```

But i also need

```
18-02-15     0
19-02-15     0
20-02-15     0
```

Which are in the future, but how.....

Comment: The best way to solve this is to use a calendar table, where you have an entry for every day in the future, and you can simply join with your transaction table.  If your data architects are totally against creating a table like this, you can use a table expression to generate the list of dates for you.

Answer (score 0):

I bruteforced it, it works, comment if you know of a more elegant way, they have started to call me Dr. Frankenstein over here :(

```
select distinct to_char((current_timestamp - ( DAYOFWEEK(CURRENT_timestamp)) DAYS + 0 days ), 'DD-MM-YY') as date, count(ticketid) from incident where to_char(creationdate, 'DD-MM-YY') = to_char((current_timestamp - ( DAYOFWEEK(CURRENT_timestamp)) DAYS + 0 days ), 'DD-MM-YY')
union
select distinct to_char((current_timestamp - ( DAYOFWEEK(CURRENT_timestamp)) DAYS + 1 days), 'DD-MM-YY') as date, count(ticketid) from incident where to_char(creationdate, 'DD-MM-YY') = to_char((current_timestamp - ( DAYOFWEEK(CURRENT_timestamp)) DAYS + 1 days ), 'DD-MM-YY')
union
select distinct to_char((current_timestamp - ( DAYOFWEEK(CURRENT_timestamp)) DAYS + 2 days ), 'DD-MM-YY') as date, count(ticketid) from incident where to_char(creationdate, 'DD-MM-YY') = to_char((current_timestamp - ( DAYOFWEEK(CURRENT_timestamp)) DAYS + 2 days ), 'DD-MM-YY')
union
select distinct to_char((current_timestamp - ( DAYOFWEEK(CURRENT_timestamp)) DAYS + 3 days ), 'DD-MM-YY') as date, count(ticketid) from incident where to_char(creationdate, 'DD-MM-YY') = to_char((current_timestamp - ( DAYOFWEEK(CURRENT_timestamp)) DAYS + 3 days ), 'DD-MM-YY')
union
select distinct to_char((current_timestamp - ( DAYOFWEEK(CURRENT_timestamp)) DAYS + 4 days ), 'DD-MM-YY') as date, count(ticketid) from incident where to_char(creationdate, 'DD-MM-YY') = to_char((current_timestamp - ( DAYOFWEEK(CURRENT_timestamp)) DAYS + 4 days ), 'DD-MM-YY')
union
select distinct to_char((current_timestamp - ( DAYOFWEEK(CURRENT_timestamp)) DAYS + 5 days ), 'DD-MM-YY') as date, count(ticketid) from incident where to_char(creationdate, 'DD-MM-YY') = to_char((current_timestamp - ( DAYOFWEEK(CURRENT_timestamp)) DAYS + 5 days ), 'DD-MM-YY')
union
select distinct to_char((current_timestamp - ( DAYOFWEEK(CURRENT_timestamp)) DAYS + 6 days ), 'DD-MM-YY') as date, count(ticketid) from incident where to_char(creationdate, 'DD-MM-YY') = to_char((current_timestamp - ( DAYOFWEEK(CURRENT_timestamp)) DAYS + 6 days ), 'DD-MM-YY')
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, if you're dealing with timestamps, [don't use `BETWEEN`](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common).  As a positive, contiguous-range type, an inclusive upper-bound will produce incorrect results (the blog post is specifically about SQL Server and date/time/timestamp types, but the problem is really due to how numbers are represented).

Next, you're attempting to group by day, but doing so via casting to character is going to keep the DB from using an index to fulfill that part of the query.

So what we want is a range query.  We'll use a recursive CTE to build the set of dates to use, but you could also use a calendar table (hands down, probably the best analysis table to build).

```
WITH Date_Range AS (SELECT start AS incidentDate, 1 AS daysElapsed,
                           TIMESTAMP(start) AS dayStart, 
                           TIMESTAMP(start + 1 DAY) AS dayEnd
                    FROM (VALUES(CURRENT_DATE
                                  - (DAYOFWEEK_ISO(CURRENT_DATE) + 1) DAYS)) T(start)
                    UNION ALL
                    SELECT incidentDate + 1 DAY, daysElapsed + 1, 
                           dayEnd, dayEnd + 1 DAY
                    FROM Date_Range
                    WHERE daysElapsed < 7)

SELECT incidentDate, COUNT(Incident.internalPriority) AS close
FROM Date_Range
LEFT JOIN Incident
       ON Incident.internalPriority >= 3
          AND Incident.creationDate >= Date_Range.dayStart
          AND Incident.creationDate < Date_Range.dayEnd
GROUP BY incidentDate
```

(not tested, as I lack a DB2 instance to work against.  Should be close, though)

Please note:

- I've used `DAYOFWEEK_ISO(...)`, because vanilla `DAYOFWEEK(...)` gives different results depending on the current culture context (ie, you're clearly expecting Sunday to be 1, but many non-US cultures use Monday as the first day of the week...).  Doing it this way removes that potential problem.
  Oh, if it *currently* is Saturday, it still goes back a week, which I assume was the intended behavior.
- The code assumes `creationDate` is an absolute (UTC) timestamp, not a local one (with a timezone).  You'd need to make changes if this is not the case.

---

Your original query had the following problems:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN internalPriority >= 3
         THEN 1
         ELSE 0 END)
```

... sometimes, this kind of thing is the only way to get this information.  The problem is that it probably requires a table scan to take place (the db will need to read all values of `internalPriority` to be able to run the `CASE`).  It's usually better to make it a join or other filtering condition, which would allow it to check via an index (assuming you have something it can use).

```
SELECT DISTINCT (CURRENT_timestamp - (DAYOFWEEK(CURRENT_timestamp) - 0) DAYS - (HOUR(current_timestamp)) HOURS - (MINUTE(current_timestamp)) MINUTE) AS MONDAY_OF_CURRENT_WEEK_DATE
FROM Incident
```

... okay:

1. You go through *every* row in the table, perform the date math on every row (which returns a constant result), then throw most of it away because of `DISTINCT`.  Ouch.  If you need a single row, either construct it via using `VALUES(...)`, or the existing single-row dummy table (`sysibm/sysdummy1`).
2. You miss seconds and fractional seconds.  Rows are going to end up assigned to the wrong date.  Thankfully, the type returned from `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` ignores DST/timezones (essentially, it's UTC), or the fact you kept using the register could have changed the day you were looking at.

   BETWEEN

Please, don't use this.  For anything except an integer **count**, you need either an exclusive upper-bound (`<` - for positive values), or an exclusive lower bound (`>` - negative values).  Don't use it with integers for consistency.

```
GROUP BY TO_CHAR(creationdate, 'DD-MM-YY')
```

... as I already mentioned, grouping on the result of a function call is going to prevent the DB from using an index to fulfill your query.  Avoid behavior like this whenever possible (and formatting is really something to do in your display-layer code anyways).